# Change in an instance of class type is not reflected in other reference

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uicollectionviewlayout

**Context**

I'm constructing a UICollectionViewLayout using NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem and NSCollectionLayoutSection.

The steps I did are:

1. Instantiate an NSCollectionLayoutSection, named as section
2. Instantiate an NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem, named as decoration
3. Assign decoration to the array section.decorationItems
4. Update decoration by populating its contentInsets

However, the update I did in step 4 is not reflected in section.decorationItems. (Swapping step 3 and 4 fixes the issue but still doesn't explain the problem.)

**Question**

[NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem is a class, hence reference type.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutdecorationitem) Why the change is not reflected in the array `section.decorationItems`? I'm not familiar with objective-c, is NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem something like an immutable class in objc?

**Code snippet**

```
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group) // Step 1
let decoration = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: Self.sectionBackgroundDecorationElementKind) // Step 2
section.decorationItems = [decoration] // Step 3
print("before change \(section.decorationItems)")
decoration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5) // Step 4 --> change not reflected in section.decorationItems
print("after change \(section.decorationItems)") // same output as "before change"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with my own class instead of `NSCollectionLayoutSection`. Can you actually give a [mcve]?

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for checking. So far I only find this behaviour on `NSCollectionLayoutSection`. Please refer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bondxf/9b197dcee2ab0ad03c97f3b804a95bcd) for a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you assign to `section.decorationItems`, a copy is made of the instances you passed in. So `section.decorationItems[0]` is a copy of your `decoration`, but is also an entirely different instance. That's why changes you make to one aren't affecting the other. You can see this in the debugger as the memory addresses are different.

If you want to change a value after assigning to `section.decorationItems`, you'll have to do it like `section.decorationItems[0].contentInsets = ...`, or perhaps reassign to `section.decorationItems` with the updated instances, so it can make fresh copies.

There are a number of places in `UIKit` where a copy is made when you assign some instance of a class to provide some configuration. Even though it's a reference type. Usually the documentation mentions it, but it doesn't for `NSCollectionLayoutSection`.

Comment: This answer appears correct. It seems to be an unfortunate side effect of the order of calls. The documentation says @NSCopying var edgeSpacing: NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing? { get set } is called before applying the insets. This returns a copy for some reason, hence the reference is changed. Hence the original will still be in the array and decoration will now be a copy with the insets. I would try printing decoration after assignment of decoration.contentInsets = ... to verify.